# Issue in rendering styles to ng-x accordion

Tags: angular

I used ng-x accordion in angular2, I rendered my accordion came up fine... But the problem is I couldnt add any styles to the template given by ng-x accordion. In my  rendered component css, I used styles say for .panel-group and .panel-heading but nothing is rendering

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

can you post your code here for better understanding?

Some advise though.
Look into the hierarchy of your css files on your page. Another css file's styling might be over righting yours.